# Is there a way to open google drive files with your installed programs?

Tags: windows, google-drive

Sort of as if the drive was mounted in your system. I do not want to have a copy of the files locally, I'd like them to be loaded on an open attempt.

Most basically I'd like to use notepad to edit text files, paint to edit images etc.
AFAIK google drive application just makes a copy locally and synchronizes with cloud. I do not want that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many applications for doing that, although most are commercial.

Here are some free options:

- The article
  [How to Add or Remove Google Drive in Navigation Pane of File Explorer in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/48991-add-remove-google-drive-navigation-pane-windows-10-a.html)
  contains a `.reg` and a `.bat` files that do just that.
- [Boxcryptor for Individuals](https://www.boxcryptor.com/en/for-individuals/)
  has limited free accounts and supports encrypted Google Drive storage.
- [RaiDrive](https://www.raidrive.com/)
  has a limited free account.
- [rclone mount](https://rclone.org/commands/rclone_mount/)
  is a Linux-oriented product
  mounts Google Drive as a FUSE file-system and so requires on Windows
  also installing
  [WinFsp](http://www.secfs.net/winfsp/).
  Using it for Google Drive is described in
  [here](https://rclone.org/drive/).
- [DokanCloudFS](https://github.com/viciousviper/DokanCloudFS)
  is an open-source Github project that is said to be somewhat slow.

For commercial products there is a large choice.
Here is a list in no particular order:
[ExpanDrive](https://www.expandrive.com/),
[NetDrive](http://www.netdrive.net/),
[WebDrive](https://webdrive.com/),
[Visual Subst](https://www.ntwind.com/software/visual-subst.html),
[StableBit CloudDrive](https://stablebit.com/CloudDrive),
[CloudMounter](https://cloudmounter.net/mount-cloud-drive-win.html),
[Mountain Duck](https://mountainduck.io/),
[CloudMounter](https://www.eltima.com/mount-google-drive-win.html).